# Hibernate sql exception when table empty

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jtds

The following code causes an exception when the Job table has no rows.

```
public List<Job> getAll(int currentPage, int pageSize) {
    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(Job.class).addOrder(Order.asc("id"))
        .setFirstResult(currentPage * pageSize).setMaxResults(pageSize)
        .setFetchSize(pageSize).list();
}
```

I am using SQL Server and the JTDS driver.

The error i get is

```
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet may only be accessed in a forward direction.
 net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.checkScrollable(JtdsResultSet.java:319)
 net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.absolute(JtdsResultSet.java:716)
 org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.absolute(DelegatingResultSet.java:335)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.advance(Loader.java:1469)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1783)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
 org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:95)
 org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
 org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
```

Comment: Any ideas on how i can avoid this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is associated with trying to page an empty table. 
drop these:
.setFirstResult(currentPage * pageSize).setMaxResults(pageSize)
.setFetchSize(pageSize)
and you should be able to query the empty table without issue.
If you want to page the data, run a regular query first, then page the data with your query after you know you have data to page.

Comment: It works fine when using MySQL.  It seems to only fail with SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Adding following property to persistence.xml solves this issue for me (jboss7, hibernate4)

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset" value="false" />
```

Alternative solution with changed dialect (not checked by me) - https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2452163

Comment: Solved the forward direction issue for me on SQL Server 2000 with JTDS 1.2.7 when using setFirstResult(), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem, and after looking around for a while I was adviced by a coworker to change the hibernate dialect from this:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

to this

```
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect
```

and it solved my problem.

Posting just as a note for people to check their dialect.